# How to secure s3 objects to be deleted by unwanted behavior?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I hope this is the right place to ask:

---

**TL;DR**

The software is able to interact with s3 through: PUT, GET, DELETE

- Goal: Secure objects from unwanted behavior of software (mainly DELETE)
- Already done: Enable  Versioning
- Not suitable (I think): WORM, since PUT, GET, DELETE has to be allowed at any given time

Ideas what else to do?

---

**Following I want to achieve:**

Im running a software that is able to PUT, GET and DELETE objects to and out of a bucket. Through versioning we already secured the data having different versions and not complete deletions of the objects. What is missing now, is a way to secure the objects from accidental "complete" deletions through the software by unwanted behavior from the software, if still possible by ticking the above mentioned steps.

Are there any hints or solutions that you used or did?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete deletions"? Are you saying that you want to prevent _all versions_ of an object from being deleted?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, thats right. But after digging into the docs again, i found what i needed. I guess after trying to work with AWS s3 the first time it was too much information to process at that moment. Somehow it made click and i got it. What a good coffee and a break is able to do ;) .. will edit the question and solution again so it makes more sense. Sorry for the unnecessary blabla and helplessness from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-with-s3-actions.html):

> **DELETE Object permissions**
>
> You can delete objects either by explicitly calling the DELETE Object API or by configuring its lifecycle (see [Managing your storage lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)) so that Amazon S3 can remove the objects when their lifetime expires. To explicitly block users or accounts from deleting objects, you must explicitly deny them `s3:DeleteObject`, `s3:DeleteObjectVersion`, and `s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration` permissions.

So you could add a deny policy for the `s3:DeleteObjectVersion` and `s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration` API-calls.

This should still allow the regular `s3:DeleteObject`, which is backed up by versioning, but prohibit users from permanently deleting a *specific* version.

The `s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration` would stop them from adding a lifecycle policy that removes old versions of objects.

I'd add these as a bucket policy to the bucket.

Comment: Thank you. Just clicking on the link to the docs and reading it again after a break helped a lot. Sorry for the other work you put into this now. Next time i will be more careful when to ask :)

Comment: No worries - if it helped, feel free to mark the answer as accepted to let other users know this is solved.